# Safequarding against crashes while swapping out NSFetchedResultsController for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to swap the NSFetchedResultsController used for a UITableView, but it takes a few lines of code and I'm worried that another thread could try to access it halfway through and cause the app to crash. Here's the code I'm currently using:

The fetched results controller is created in the getter if it does not already exist, so the next time the table view tries to access it, it will be regenerated.

```
- (void)regenerateFetchedResultsController
{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;

    [self loadData]; // Loads data into the fetched results controller.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'd guess that if something tried to access the FOC in the middle of this method things would go wrong, so I thought I would use UITableView's `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` methods and the start and end of the method.

However, it seems you can't have `reloadData` between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, so I don't really know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All table view data source methods (`numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, ...) are only called on the *main thread*. Therefore, if you run your `regenerateFetchedResultsController` also on the main thread, it will not happen that any other method accesses the FRC in that time.

It may depend on what `[self loadData]` exactly does, but setting the fetched results controller to `nil` and letting it "auto-recreate" by calling `reloadData` is a standard pattern.